# Resembling gravity in python using pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

In this program I am creating a square that starts from (0,0) and falls increasing in speed by one each time round the loop(resembling gravity) and when it hits the bottom of the screen in jumps up to the top slowing down by one each time round the loop and then repeats. The code below works up until the square reaches back to the top the first time, where it gets stuck. Any suggestions as to how to fix this? Thanks.

```
rect_x = 0
rect_y = 0
speed = 0

rect_change_x = 10
rect_change_y = 0

# Set the width and height of the screen [width,height]
size = [800,600]
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

pygame.display.set_caption("My Lovely Game")

#Loop until the user clicks the close button.
done = False

# Used to manage how fast the screen updates
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# -------- Main Program Loop -----------
while done == False:

    for event in pygame.event.get(): # User did something
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: # If user clicked close
            done = True # Flag that we are done so we exit this loop

    if rect_x > 750 or rect_x < 0:
        rect_change_x *= -1

    if rect_y > 550:
        rect_change_y = -rect_change_y


    if rect_y < 0:
        rect_change_y = 0

    rect_x += rect_change_x
    rect_y += rect_change_y

    screen.fill(black)
    rect_change_y = rect_change_y + 1
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,white,[rect_x,rect_y,50,50])
    pygame.display.set_caption(str(rect_change_y))

    pygame.display.flip()

    # Limit to 30 frames per second
    clock.tick(30)

pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if rect_y < 0:
    rect_change_y = 0
```

This is the line causing the problem. When the rect goes above the screen's top edge, you set its y velocity to 0. Then, since its velocity is zero, it doesn't come down below the screen's edge that frame. Although you increase velocity by one each frame, it gets reset to zero again the next frame, and so on forever.

I suggest changing the block so that it cancels out all upwards velocity, but not downwards.

```
if rect_y < 0:
    rect_change_y = max(rect_change_y, 0)
```

Alternatively, for an elastic collision, just flip the sign.

```
if rect_y < 0:
    rect_change_y *= -1
```